# Getting SRID Well Known Text (WKT) metadata from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, metadata, well-known-text

The SRID metadata is showed by, e.g., [this web page](https://epsg.io/6211#s_html_code):

> <sub>Definition: Well Known Text (WKT)</sub>
>
> <sub>PROJCS["UTM Zone 24, Northern Hemisphere",
>
> GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
>
> DATUM["unknown",
>
> SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101],
>
> TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
>
> PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
>
> UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
>
> PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
>
> PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
>
> PARAMETER["central_meridian",-39],
>
> PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
>
> PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
>
> PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
>
> UNIT["Meter",1],
>
> AUTHORITY["epsg","6211"]]</sub>

This information is on my local database, but how can I see it?

A function like `SRID_AsText(srid)`. Or some complex PostgreSQL query over all PostGIS tables to see the SRID metadata?

Comment: does this have what you're after? https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ch04.html#spatial_ref_sys

Comment: @DPSSpatial yes, solved! Prefer that I delete the question or you answer it?

Comment: Oh good! Well I added an answer in case you decide to keep your question. Glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page should have what you're after, the spatial_ref_sys table in PostGIS:

https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#spatial_ref_sys

Comment: The correct/updated link is at [postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#spatial_ref_sys), see  last paragraph at  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/295412/7505